# powershell Gui progress bar with batch file

Tags: user-interface, powershell, batch-file

I found this gui progress bar on a different site. The way that it explains, should solve my problem which when the job is running not let the gui freeze.

However, since I'm dealing with batch files (installing applications) I need to do a foreach app and install them one by one and not let the gui freeze.

Here is the link to the site [link](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2011/07/15/primalforms-2011-creating-responsive-loops/)

```
EDIT: UPDATE the SCRIPT. so far this works but all batch files install at the same time which is causing them to fail. I have more applications but for testing I just added 3.
```

I am only assuming that the $job is not passing its status to "updatescript" and "completedscript"

```
$Appname = @("Adobe_FlashPlayer", "Acrobat_Reader, "Microsoft_RDP_8.1")

$formJobProgress_Load={
#TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
$timer1.Interval = 1000
$timer1.Tag = 0
$timer1.Start()
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
}

$formMain_FormClosed=[System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler]{
#Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs]
#Stop any pending jobs
Stop-JobTracker
}

$timerJobTracker_Tick={
Update-JobTracker   
}
#region Job Tracker
$JobTrackerList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
function Add-JobTracker
{

Param (
    #[ValidateNotNull()]
    #[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$Name,
    #[ValidateNotNull()]
    #[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ScriptBlock]$CompletedScript,
    [ScriptBlock]$UpdateScript,
    [ScriptBlock]$JobScript,
    $ArgumentList = $null)

    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $JobScript -ArgumentList $ArgumentList





if($job -ne $null)
{
    #Create a Custom Object to keep track of the Job & Script Blocks
    $psObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSObject

    Add-Member -InputObject $psObject -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name Job      -Value $job
    Add-Member -InputObject $psObject -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name CompleteScript  -Value $CompletedScript
    Add-Member -InputObject $psObject -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name UpdateScript  -Value $UpdateScript

    [void]$JobTrackerList.Add($psObject)    

    #Start the Timer
    if(-not $timerJobTracker.Enabled)
    {
        $timerJobTracker.Start()
    }
}
elseif($CompletedScript -ne $null)
{
    #Failed
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $CompletedScript -ArgumentList $null
}

}
function Update-JobTracker
{
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Checks the status of each job on the list.
#>

#Poll the jobs for status updates
$timerJobTracker.Stop() #Freeze the Timer

for($index =0; $index -lt $JobTrackerList.Count; $index++)
{
    $psObject = $JobTrackerList[$index]

    if($psObject -ne $null) 
    {
        if($psObject.Job -ne $null)
        {
            if($psObject.Job.State -ne "Running")
            {               
                #Call the Complete Script Block
                if($psObject.CompleteScript -ne $null)
                {
                    #$results = Receive-Job -Job $psObject.Job
                    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $psObject.CompleteScript -   ArgumentList $psObject.Job
                }

                $JobTrackerList.RemoveAt($index)
                Remove-Job -Job $psObject.Job
                $index-- #Step back so we don't skip a job
            }
            elseif($psObject.UpdateScript -ne $null)
            {
                #Call the Update Script Block
                Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $psObject.UpdateScript -ArgumentList $psObject.Job
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $JobTrackerList.RemoveAt($index)
        $index-- #Step back so we don't skip a job
    }
}

if($JobTrackerList.Count -gt 0)
{
    $timerJobTracker.Start()#Resume the timer   
}   
}
function Stop-JobTracker
{
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Stops and removes all Jobs from the list.
#>
#Stop the timer
$timerJobTracker.Stop()

#Remove all the jobs
while($JobTrackerList.Count -gt 0)
{
    $job = $JobTrackerList[0].Job
    $JobTrackerList.RemoveAt(0)
    Stop-Job $job
    Remove-Job $job
}
}#endregion


$buttonStartJob_Click= {
$progressbaroverlay1.Value = 0
$progressbaroverlay1.Step = 1
$progressbaroverlay1.Maximum = $Appname.Count
$this.Enabled = $false
$buttonStartJob.Enabled = $false

#Create a New Job using the Job Tracker
foreach ($app in $Appname)
{
    $install = "C:\pstools\Update\cmd\$app\install.cmd"
    $run = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
    Add-JobTracker -Name "test"`
                   -JobScript {
        param (
            [string]$batchFilePath
        )
        Write-Verbose "Launching: [$batchFilePath]" -Verbose
        Set-Location $env:windir
        & ($run, $batchFilePath)

    }` -ArgumentList $install -CompletedScript {

        Param ($Job)
        #$progressbar1.Value = 100
        #Enable the Button
        $ProgressBarOverlay1.PerformStep()
        $buttonStartJob.ImageIndex = -1
        $buttonStartJob.Enabled = $true
}`
    -UpdateScript {
        Param ($Job)
        $results = Receive-Job -Job $Job | Select-Object -Last 1

        if ($results -is [int])
        {
            $progressbaroverlay1.Value = $results
        }

    }
}
}
$timer1_Tick={

    #TODO: Place custom script here

    #if ([timespan]::FromSeconds($timerUpdate.Tag) -ge     [timespan]::Fromminutes(1))
    IF($progressbaroverlay1.Value -eq 100)
    {

        $timerUpdate.stop()
        $formSampleTimer.Close()
    }
    else
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
        $label1.Text = [timespan]::FromSeconds($timer1.Tag++)
    }

}
```

Comment: You have posted several times trying to get help related to this and while we have given you functional answers it doesn't seem like you have put much effort into the code yourself. The code above has very little from the accepted answer of the question you asked just 5 days ago [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569523/powershell-call-batch-within-scriptblock). You are way too hung up on that [Sapien script](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2011/07/15/primalforms-2011-creating-responsive-loops/). My best advise it to use the built in progress bar, or ask for advise on the Sapien forums.

Comment: Hi, It's not that I'm not trying.t Trust me I've been trying to write my code. But I'm stuck on this process so that's why I keep asking in different ways.

Comment: I actually figured out how to call it. Now my problem is everything is running back to back without waiting for the first one to finish.

Comment: Update your question with your semi-functional code, and I'm betting we can get it working right. I have a feeling you are using jobs, and just need a well placed Wait-Job

Comment: @TheMadTechnician just updated. I put the whole script. I tried adding While(get-job -state 'running'){wait-job} but that completely froze the GUI.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you either copied this from somewhere and modified it to kind of work for you, or you used something like PowerGUI or Sapien to generate the script for you because this is seriously hard to read code in my opinion.

If I understand it right you create `$JobTrackerList` as an `ArrayList` object. Then for each application that you want to install you add a `PSCustomObject` to that `ArrayList` with 3 properties, one being a `Job` that runs in the background, one being a script to run when that is completed, and one being a script to update your progress bar. So each object has a background job that is running, and this is the root issue at this point. But wait, we're not done, you have a timer going on (not actually defined in the code you gave us) that runs, and every 1000 ticks it stops, checks each job, if it is completed it runs the "completed" scriptblock that you defined for that object, and then removes the object from the `ArrayList`. If it is still not completed it updates the progressbar with the "update" scriptblock. Then it starts the timer again.

Here's what I think needs to happen for this to work like you want... You need to go ahead and make your `ArrayList`, and add objects to it for each application that you want to run, but do not create jobs for them all! Once you create all the objects start a job for the first application (and add it as a member of the object like you did before). Then when your script checks for completed jobs, before it deletes the object it is looking at it should start the job for the next object.

So, that's going to require a bit of re-write of your code. I'm not sure where to really start with this, because the code that you have is so very different to how I would have written it, so I've given you my suggestions, and now I'll let you run with it from here. If you need help writing the code (at least try first) let me know and I'll see what I can do. Probably not today, I'm dead tired and not on my A game, but I'm sure I can come up with something tomorrow if you end up needing help.

**Edit:** Ok, I think I have code that should do what you want, and work with what you already have in place:

```
$formJobProgress_Load={
    #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
    $timer1.Interval = 1000
    $timer1.Tag = 0
    $timer1.Start()
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
}

$timerJobTracker_Tick={
    $timerJobTracker.Stop() #Freeze the Timer
    for($index =0; $index -lt $JobTrackerList.Count; $index++){
        $psObject = $JobTrackerList[$index]
        if($psObject -ne $null -AND $psObject.Job -ne $null -AND $psObject.Job.State -ne "Running"){
            #Perform old 'Complete' scriptblock to update progressbar
            $ProgressBarOverlay1.PerformStep()

            #Check if this is the only job, and if not start the next one
            If($JobTrackerList.count -gt 1){
                $NextJob = $JobTrackerList[($index+1)]
                $NextJob.Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $NextJob.JobScript
            }
            $JobTrackerList.RemoveAt($index)
            Remove-Job -Job $psObject.Job
            $index-- #Step back so we don't skip a job
        }Else{
            $results = Receive-Job -Job $Job | Select-Object -Last 1
            if ($results -is [int]){
                $progressbaroverlay1.Value = $results
            }
        }
    }

    if($JobTrackerList.Count -gt 0){
        $timerJobTracker.Start()#Resume the timer   
    }
}

$formMain_FormClosed=[System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler]{
    #Stop the timer
    $timerJobTracker.Stop()

    #Remove all the jobs
    while($JobTrackerList.Count -gt 0){
        $job = $JobTrackerList[0].Job
        $JobTrackerList.RemoveAt(0)
        Stop-Job $job
        Remove-Job $job
    }
}


$Appname = @("Adobe_FlashPlayer", "Acrobat_Reader", "Microsoft_RDP_8.1")

$JobTrackerList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$buttonStartJob_Click= {
    $progressbaroverlay1.Value = 0
    $progressbaroverlay1.Step = 1
    $progressbaroverlay1.Maximum = $Appname.Count
    $this.Enabled = $false
    $buttonStartJob.Enabled = $false

    ForEach($App in $Appname){

        $install = "C:\pstools\Update\cmd\$app\install.cmd"
        $run = "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
        $JobScript = {
            Write-Verbose "Launching: [$install]" -Verbose
            Set-Location $env:windir
            & $install
        }

        [void]$JobTrackerList.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            'Application' = $Name
            'JobScript' = $JobScript
            'Job' = $null
        }))
    }

    $JobTrackerList[0].Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $JobTrackerList[0].JobScript
}

$timer1_Tick={

    #TODO: Place custom script here

    #if ([timespan]::FromSeconds($timerUpdate.Tag) -ge     [timespan]::Fromminutes(1))
    IF($progressbaroverlay1.Value -eq 100)
    {

        $timerUpdate.stop()
        $formSampleTimer.Close()
    }
    else
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
        $label1.Text = [timespan]::FromSeconds($timer1.Tag++)
    }

}
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I added this but it doesn't start any of the apps. I'm assuming the script block isn't working with the index. Because if I kill the process, it asks for an "id' to stop the job. As far as the code it self yes i copied it from another site (Sapien) and tried to implement it for what I'm trying to do. I shared the link in the original post. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: After all the testing and playing around with your code. It comes down to my main question again I guess. Why doesn't the script block run cmd files? That was my first question for what I was trying to do. I need to read more about this I guess. Can't pass the install.cmd to the script block.

Comment: Are you using Sapien, or just a bit of their code? Is there more to your code than what is shown in your question above?

Comment: I am using sapien yes. But no more code than what's above.

Comment: I am not well versed in Sapien, but does it, at some point, state `Launching: [C:\pstools\Update\cmd\Adobe_FlashPlayer\install.cmd]` when you run the script? The code you have here looks like it is part of a larger script that has a GUI, with buttons, and a progress bar (among other things). Do you see all that when you run the script in Sapien?

Comment: That's one of the things I noticed and forgot to mention. No, it doesn't even output "launching: c:\pstools\update\cmd\..."  I do have a button and the progress bar. They do launch without errors. When I click the button to start the process nothing happens. I tried moving the write-verbose outside of the scriptblock and it works. That scriptblock seems like it's just not working.

Comment: Yeah, this really looks like it's a Sapien issue and you probably need to talk to them to get it to work. Nothing in your code actually creates a button or a progress bar, so there is obviously more going on than just the script above, and you probably need to get on their forums for help there. Straight PowerShell, the script looks fairly solid, just strangely formatted due to the Sapien aspect of it.

Comment: I already posted on their forums too but almost no responses. Got only one response saying he doesn't understand. I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much..!